# Bigquery Recursion SQL and using it in subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

**Running a recursive CTE in Bigquery and using the sub-expressions.**

The following code is the PostgreSQL version for computing the ELO of a player. ELO is given by the following formula.
[image: Formula]

K = 32 , R1 and R2 correspond to the ELO ratings of Player 1 and Player 2 resp.  R' is the new rating after a game. Is there an easy way to replicate this in Bigquery? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE plays (
  game_number INT          NOT NULL, -- must be consecutive and start at 1!
  p1name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, -- first player
  p1score     FLOAT        NOT NULL, -- 0 or 1
  p2name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, -- second player
  p2score     FLOAT        NOT NULL  -- 0 or 1
);
INSERT INTO plays VALUES
  (1, 'Elliot', 0, 'Brendan', 1),
  (2, 'Bob', 1, 'Brendan', 0),
  (3, 'Bob', 1, 'Elliot', 0),
  (4, 'Jane', 1, 'Bob', 0),
  (5, 'Bob', 0, 'Brendan', 1),
  (6, 'Jane', 1, 'Elliot', 0);

WITH RECURSIVE p(current_game_number) AS (
  WITH players AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT p1name AS player_name
    FROM plays
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT p2name
    FROM plays
  )
  SELECT
    0               AS game_number,
    player_name,
    1000.0 :: FLOAT AS previous_elo,
    1000.0 :: FLOAT AS new_elo
  FROM players
  UNION ALL
  (
    WITH previous_elos AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM p
    )
    SELECT
      plays.game_number,
      player_name,
      previous_elos.new_elo AS previous_elo,
      round(CASE WHEN player_name NOT IN (p1name, p2name)
        THEN previous_elos.new_elo
            WHEN player_name = p1name
              THEN previous_elos.new_elo + 32.0 * (p1score - (r1 / (r1 + r2)))
            ELSE previous_elos.new_elo + 32.0 * (p2score - (r2 / (r1 + r2))) END)
    FROM plays
      JOIN previous_elos
        ON current_game_number = plays.game_number - 1
      JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT
             pow(10.0, (SELECT new_elo
                        FROM previous_elos
                        WHERE current_game_number = plays.game_number - 1 AND player_name = p1name) / 400.0) AS r1,
             pow(10.0, (SELECT new_elo
                        FROM previous_elos
                        WHERE current_game_number = plays.game_number - 1 AND player_name = p2name) / 400.0) AS r2
           ) r
        ON TRUE
  )
)
SELECT
  player_name,
  (
    SELECT new_elo
    FROM p
    WHERE t.player_name = p.player_name
    ORDER BY current_game_number DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )                    AS elo,
  count(CASE WHEN previous_elo < new_elo
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END) AS wins,
  count(CASE WHEN previous_elo > new_elo
    THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END) AS losses
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM p
    WHERE previous_elo <> new_elo
    ORDER BY current_game_number, player_name
  ) t
GROUP BY player_name
ORDER BY elo DESC;
```